# Django - Admin - How to override change_list template for Model Proxy?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-templates

I made a simple Django app.  I have one model "Visitor".  My goal is to have two tables appear in the Django admin.  One with all of the visitors and one with only those for today.

I got everything working with the code below by following [these instructions](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates). But I'm not sure how to override just the change_list.html for just VisitorExpectedTodayProxy.

I tried following the [instructions here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates) and I created `Site/templates/admin/VisitorLog/VisitorExpectedTodayProxy/change_list.html` and made my changes there, but it doesn't seem to be picking it up.

**Models.py**

```
class Visitor(models.Model):
    visit_datetime = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    visitor_name = models.CharField(max_length=500)

#Make dummy models for different object views in admin interface
class VisitorExpectedTodayProxy(Visitor):
    class Meta:
        proxy=True
        verbose_name = "Visitor"
        verbose_name_plural = "Today's Visitors and Regular Visitors"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try lowercasing your folder names.

> Note, that the admin app will
>   lowercase the model name when looking
>   for the directory, so make sure you
>   name the directory in all lowercase if
>   you are going to run your app on a
>   case-sensitive filesystem.

Also, have you gone through the checklist of making sure your templates directory is working at all? `TEMPLATE_DIRS` needs to contain this templates folder of yours, and make sure the `filesystem` template loader comes before the `app_directories` loader.

Finally, you can point to a template via a ModelAdmin attribute: 
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.change_list_template

Answer (score 7):

On top of lowercasing your paths to look like:

```
templates/admin/visitorlog/visitorexpectedtodayproxy/change_list.html
```

The content of your change_list.html should extend the default admin/change_list:

```
{% extends "admin/change_list.html" %}
```

You can customise the different section of this page by looking at the various block templates in the django source code:

```
django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/change_list.html
```

Comment: I just copied change_list.html into the directory and modified it there.  Is there a better way?