# Change the column width in the django admin panel

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-admin, width

My admin.py looks like this:

```
class ChangeAdmin(GuardedModelAdmin):
    form = ChangeForm
    search_fields = ('RFC', 'Ticket_Number', 'User_Email', 'Change_Details')
    list_display = ('RFC', 'Ticket_Number', 'User_Requested_Time', 'Start_Time', 'End_Time',
                    'User_Email', 'Line_of_Business', 'Conf_Call_Details', 'Region',
                    'Summary', 'Description', 'Change_Details', 'Site_code', 'Configuration_Item',
                    'Plan_Owner', 'Plan_status', 'Change_Owner', 'Implementer', 'Validator')
    date_hierarchy = 'Start_Time'
    list_select_related = True
```

As is evident,there are lots of list fields in the table display. This is screwing up the way the data is being shown in the columns..See screenshot:

[image]

How can I resize the column width in the django admin ?

Comment: I think you had to override the django template use link [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5488159/django-admin-how-to-override-change-list-template-for-model-proxy)

Comment: The accepted answer here literally said to refer to another Stack Overflow question (or else a forum guide) without any direct explanation. It's hard to give a more textbook example of a duplicate question.

Answer (score 5):

admin.py:

```
class MyClassAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    class Media:
        css = {
            'all': ('fancy.css',)
        }
```

fancy.css:

```
.column-foo {
    width: 20px;
}
```

where "foo" is a field name.

Source:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/media/

Answer (score 2):

Tested on Django 3.2, use `min-width` instead of `width`.

```py
class MyClassAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    class Media:
        css = {
            'all': ('css/fancy.css',)
        }
```

```css
.column-foo {
    min-width: 20px;
}
```

Comment: why its not working

Answer (score 1):

The previous answers did not work for me, perhaps they are outdated. I added padding to the column headers to make them wider.

Create custom css file in your static folder and override the "change_list.html" file

change_list.html (located at /templates/admin/change_list.html)

```
{% extends "admin/change_list.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block extrahead %}
    <!-- Custom -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/custom_changelists.css' %}">
{% endblock %}
```

custom_changelists.css

```
.column-FIELD_NAME{
    padding-right: 150px !important;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. By adding the version of your program you could improve the quality of your answer

Answer (score 0):

I've used this approach with django-suit:

admin.py

```
class GuardedAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class Media:
        js = ('js/guarded_admin.js',)
```

js/guarded_admin.js

```
$(function(){
  $(".guarded-column.column-guarded").attr("width", "100px;");
})
```

You just need to figure out what the column name is in your case and change it in the above code.

**Update**

I recently tried this and it worked (given your column is called reports):

```
$('.reports-column').find('span').attr('style', 'width:150px;')
```

Comment: Try 2 things. First test your jquery selector in your browser to ensure it works. If it works fine in the browser dev tool, then try putting the command in a delay (to diagnose) like this: setTimeout(function() { $(".guarded-column.column-guarded").attr("width", "100px;"); }, 1000);

Comment: the content of every cell is small table for me, so I set the width for this table inside. Such way grapelli respects the width of the content and the problem solved for me

Answer (score 0):

You can override `forms.ModelForm` then assign `ChangeForm` to [form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin.form) to change **the width of each column** in Django Admin as shown below. *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910169/resize-fields-in-django-admin#answer-72847861) also explains other options to change **the width of columns** in Django Admin:

```py
class ChangeForm(forms.ModelForm): # Here
    class Meta:
        widgets = {
            'RFC': forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':'20'}),
            'Ticket_Number' : forms.NumberInput(attrs={
                'style': 'width:20ch'
            }),
            'User_Email' : forms.EmailInput(attrs={
                'style': 'width:20ch'
            }),
            # ...
        }

class ChangeAdmin(GuardedModelAdmin):
    form = ChangeForm # Here
    search_fields = ('RFC', 'Ticket_Number', 'User_Email', 'Change_Details')
    list_display = ('RFC', 'Ticket_Number', 'User_Requested_Time', ...)
    # ...
```